# increase text font value with JButton issue

Tags: java, user-interface, fonts, jbutton, jlabel

I have to create an interface which allows the user to increase/decrease the size of a piece of text and to show the current font size value of that text.

I have two buttons, increase and decrease.
I have two labels. One label has the text "X" which needs to change size every time a button is pressed. The other label has to display the current font size value of "X".

I have managed to implement the increase/decrease method for the text, however I cannot get the value of the text to increase after clicking. The value of the text when increased only allows the user to increase it once. I want the program to be able to increase it by 5 every time the button is activated.

I believe I have to somehow store the new value of the font size and use the new value to allow me to increase/decrease even more.

If anyone could tell me how to do this, or show a solution, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
package lab3;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FontSize extends JFrame{


JButton increase, decrease;
JLabel sizeX, sizeValue;


public static void main (String[]args){

    FontSize changeFont = new FontSize();
    changeFont.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    changeFont.setTitle("Increase/Decrease Font Size");
    changeFont.setSize(900,700);
    changeFont.setVisible(true);
    changeFont.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

}


public FontSize(){

    increase = new JButton("increase");
    increase.setBackground(Color.white);
    increase.setFont(increase.getFont().deriveFont(30.0f));
    add(increase);

    decrease = new JButton("decrease");
    decrease.setBackground(Color.white);
    decrease.setFont(decrease.getFont().deriveFont(30.0f));
    add(decrease);

    sizeX = new JLabel("X", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    sizeX.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    sizeX.setFont(sizeX.getFont().deriveFont(30.0f));
    add(sizeX);

    int temp = sizeX.getFont().getSize();
    sizeValue = new JLabel("",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    sizeValue.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
    sizeValue.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    sizeValue.setFont(sizeValue.getFont().deriveFont(30.0f));
    add(sizeValue);

    event e = new event();
    increase.addActionListener(e);
    decrease.addActionListener(e);


 }
public class event implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


        String operation = e.getActionCommand();
        int temp = sizeX.getFont().getSize();
        int temp2 = sizeValue.getFont().getSize();


        if(operation.equals("increase"))
            {                       
                temp = temp + 5;
                sizeX.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, temp));

                temp2 = temp2 + 5;
                sizeValue.setText(String.valueOf(temp2));

            } 
        else if(operation.equals("decrease"))
            {
                temp = temp - 5;
                sizeX.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, temp));

                temp2 = temp2 - 5;
                sizeValue.setText(String.valueOf(temp2));

            }

      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix really: on like 64 of the original code, you accidentaly are trying to count the variable *temp2* as the size of the font of it, not the actual text. I've attached a slightly refactored, as well as corrected, version of the code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FontSize extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton increase, decrease;
    private JLabel sizeX, sizeValue;

    public static void main (String[]args) {
        FontSize changeFont = new FontSize();
        changeFont.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        changeFont.setTitle("Increase/Decrease Font Size");
        changeFont.setSize(900,700);
        changeFont.setVisible(true);
        changeFont.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    }

    public FontSize(){
        increase = new JButton("increase");
        increase.setBackground(Color.white);
        increase.setFont(increase.getFont().deriveFont(30.0f));
        add(increase);

        decrease = new JButton("decrease");
        decrease.setBackground(Color.white);
        decrease.setFont(decrease.getFont().deriveFont(30.0f));
        add(decrease);

        sizeX = new JLabel("X", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        sizeX.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        sizeX.setFont(sizeX.getFont().deriveFont(30.0f));
        add(sizeX);

        int temp = sizeX.getFont().getSize();
        sizeValue = new JLabel("",SwingConstants.CENTER);
        sizeValue.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
        sizeValue.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        sizeValue.setFont(sizeValue.getFont().deriveFont(30.0f));
        add(sizeValue);

        increase.addActionListener(this);
        decrease.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String operation = e.getActionCommand();
        int temp = sizeX.getFont().getSize();
        int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(sizeValue.getText());

        if(operation.equals("increase")) {                       
            temp += 5;
            sizeX.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, temp));

            temp2 += 5;
            sizeValue.setText(String.valueOf(temp2));

        } else if(operation.equals("decrease")) {
            temp -= 5;
            sizeX.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, temp));

            temp2 -= 5;
            sizeValue.setText(String.valueOf(temp2));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helped, and best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

`int temp2 = sizeValue.getFont().getSize();` isn't the size of the font you're changing, but is the size of the font which is been used to render the label.

Try using something more like instead...

```
        String operation = e.getActionCommand();
        int temp = sizeX.getFont().getSize();

        if (operation.equals("increase")) {
            temp = temp + 5;
            sizeX.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, temp));

            sizeValue.setText(String.valueOf(temp));

        } else if (operation.equals("decrease")) {
            temp = temp - 5;
            sizeX.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, temp));

            sizeValue.setText(String.valueOf(temp));

        }
```

You may also need to call `revalidate();` and `repaint();` at the end of the `actionPerformed` method to force a refresh, but it work okay without for me

Equally, you could just something like...

```
        Font font = sizeX.getFont();

        if (operation.equals("increase")) {
            font = font.deriveFont(font.getSize() + 5f);
        } else if (operation.equals("decrease")) {
            font = font.deriveFont(font.getSize() - 5f);
        }
        sizeX.setFont(font);
        sizeValue.setText(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(font.getSize()));
```

Which allows you to maintain the font that the label was originally using, but increases/decreases it's size, but also relies on the actual `Font` size to update the display, rather the relying on calculated values...